# Poker Chips Shuffling: Top Chip Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random, poker

In order to shuffle a pile of n poker chips. They are first separated into two equal piles of size n/2. Next, chips are added by alternating from each side. The side that is chosen to have the bottom chip is randomly selected with equal probability. For instance, an initial pile with the arrangement:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (where 1 is at the top of stack and 10 is at the bottom)

following a shuffle could end up as:

6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 (if the pile with 5 was chosen to be the bottom chip)

or

1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10 (if the pile with the 10 was chosen to be the bottom chip)

If we are to start with chip #1 at the top, what is the expected number of shuffles until the chip at the top of the stack is chip #1 again.

Comment: This is an ergodic Markov Chain with a uniform stationary distribution making the expected return time $\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: Is this essentially just finding the probability of a chip being at the top? Meaning it is 1/10 and therefore 10 shuffles?